# Scheduled (automatic) Windows 8.1 maintenance slows system at times

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-task-scheduler

In Windows 8.1 the Scheduled Tasks list contains hidden tasks to run the built in disk defragmenter at various times, such as when bringing the computer out of sleep in the morning. When the defragmenter is running on a small laptop, it is almost impossible to get work done on the computer. Even clicking a menu may be delayed by many seconds. Video cannot be played.

There must be some way to turn off automatic defragmentation, or to make it happen at the user's desired times. Anyone know how to do this?

ADDED: Perhaps the slowdown is not caused by defragmentation, but by other tasks done during automatic maintenance. I have found neither explanation nor settings.

If I had designed Windows, I would have made sure that the message pump could never be dominated by an I/O operation, or by a task that refused to yield their control. At the very least, defragmentation should deliberately yield control several times a second, so it does not hog the computer and make it hang or run very slowly.

ADDED: Since disabling defragmentation, I have observed the same kind of severe slowdown at random times, most often when I wake the system from sleep in the morning. This would appear to prove that my assumption that defragmentation is the culprit is false. I have re-enabled defragmentation.

However, this leaves open the question of why regular maintenance is slowing the system down so severely. In its usual benevolent hiding of details from users, Microsoft's task scheduler gives no hints as to what tasks or process names are part of its scheduled regular maintenance. It would seem difficult to do further research to figure out why this severe slowdown happens, a few times a day.

Comment: [How to Change "Optimize Drives" Schedule Settings in Windows 8 and 8.1](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8616-optimize-drives-schedule-change-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: [Disk Defragmenter in Windows 10/8/7 explained](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disk-defragmenter-windows)

Comment: A simple google search would have found both of the above links. Please do some research before posting questions.

Comment: Disable automatic defrag and then run it manually at a time of your choosing (when you can leave the computer to do its own thing while it defrags.

Comment: I did a Web search, but did not find those two links. Perhaps my search terms were poorly chosen. You don't have to assume that I did no research.

Comment: My comments tell you what to to disable defrag. Then you can see if something else is causing your issue.

Comment: I thought we were not supposed to have back-and-forth discussions in these comments. Did I misunderstand the rules of this site? I followed your comments and found the defrag dialog box and disabled defrag. I will see if this helps. I can always do a manual defrag using Properties > Tools.

Comment: Comments are used to help clarify a question (asking for additional information for example), and to provide hints to questioners on steps they might take to find a solution. If the hints work and completely solve the problem then they should be converted to an answer and the comments cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Programs without a window / UI don't have a message pump. (I assume you're referring to the one implemented using the `GetMessage()`/`DispatchMessage()` functions in the Windows API.)

Comment: Whoops, meant this as a comment in the question.

Comment: The evidence that automatic defrag is not yielding control to the Windows message pump is that the whole system runs slowly. What is your evidence that my question is wrong?

Comment: All 32-bit Windows versions have had the ability to preempt processes and take back control for multitasking. Back in the days of 16-bit Windows we had cooperative multitasking, where applications would have to yield the CPU back to the OS (calling `GetMessage()` would do that, among other things) otherwise the system could stall. In any case, a "message pump" is involved when the application displays a UI of some sort; if it's doing entirely background work then it doesn't use a message pump.

Comment: Then why would background processes (like routine maintenance) slow down everything on the computer, even menu click operations? Something about Windows maintenance is either running at too high a priority or locking out other processes during I/O. No?